# What counts as a random object name in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In the Google Cloud Storage docs it says:

> Auto-scaling of an index range can be slowed when using sequential
>   names, such as object keys based on a sequence of numbers or
>   timestamp.

The recommendation is to use totally random object names to help with high writes.

Does that apply to paths too? For example if you had a path `/photos/` in your bucket but the object names were random:

```
myBucketName/photos/FNDHEHF-image.jpg
myBucketName/photos/XDFDADD-image.jpg
myBucketName/photos/PORFNDF-image.jpg
myBucketName/photos/PDKWNDF-image.jpg
```

Would the above shard well? or would the path `/photos/` cause problems at high write rates because it is all the same name? Because from what I understand an object name includes the entire file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire name of the file - the entire path - is considered the file name in Cloud Storage.  There is actually no such thing as "folders" in Cloud Storage.  There are just paths that impose a folder-like organization of your choosing.  Because of this, randomness anywhere in the path counts toward the total randomness of the file.

What that message is telling you not to do is use sequential numbers where the paths vary.  So, don't do this:

```
/foo/bar/1.jpg
/foo/bar/2.jpg
/foo/bar/3.jpg
....
```

Assuming that your 6 characters of randomness is evenly distributed across the full range of those 6 characters, it should be sufficient.

Comment: "randomness anywhere in the path counts towards the total randomness of the file" --- are you sure about that? I thought it was only randomness at the start of the path that helped with sharding...

Comment: If that was the requirement, then I'm sure it would have been stated in the documentation.  Randomness at the start of the path would render your storage bucket completely unusable in terms of the organization provided by folder-like separators.

Comment: Hmm. I am confused on the docs.. this is why I am asking on SO. Take a look at "Randomness after sequential prefixes is not as effective" in  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate - It seems to suggest that the randomness needs to be higher up the path or something.

Comment: All that's saying is if you need to use a sequence number, put your randomness before that number.  Anywhere before.  All the examples put it immediately before.  If you don't have a sequence number, then the location of randomness is not even relevant.

Comment: The key wording is `but the effect is limited to that prefix, with no consideration of the rest of the bucket`. This creates `hotspots` which means that certain buckets areas are well hashed where other parts are not.

Comment: @JohnHanley thus, long story short, to eliminate all hotspots and have maximum scalable sharding, have randomness at the start of the object name?

Comment: Correct. This is also the case for Alibaba, AWS and Azure cloud storage.

Comment: I see no need to unnecessarily push randomness any higher than the level of organization that you need among all the objects that need to hashed **from each other**, using the prefix that defines the group.  Forcing it at the topmost level means that you'll have organizational problems when you want to add logically separate files later on.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well the fear is that I will have a hotspot at "photos" since all my objects start with `photos/` with a random hash after that. `photos/` is a folder that will be taking many many writes.

Comment: As cited above: "but the effect is limited to that prefix, with no consideration of the rest of the bucket".  In other words, there is only "hotness" forming at distinct equivalent paths, which you will cool off with randomness within that logcal space.

Comment: What if the top most path is not necessarily something that would be equally distributed across all characters such as a user name? For example, would this type of structure create hotspots? `photos-bucket/[user_name]/[random_string].jpg`

Comment: If your app scales up to milions of users, then you're going to have a lot entropy just in the user names alone, unless they also happen to be seqentia, which would be *really* weird.

Comment: So basically that is going to potentially lead to latency? What do you mean "you're going to have a lot entropy"?

Comment: You'll have plenty of randomness in the variance of user names.  There won't be any clustering like you would with sequential strings.

Comment: Ah I see, "entropy" means randomness. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It does scale well.  However, in the app I'm currently working on, we use longer filenames (I think it's 20 characters) to drastically increase the namespace and reduce the chance of collisions.

Comment: But doesn't the object name include the entire file path? In the example I gave, wouldn't it be `photos`?

Comment: Using long object names does NOT decrease collisions in buckets. You want the first few characters to be different.

Comment: @JohnHanley would using random long object names work better? i.e. the longer the random object name the more efficient it is at high write speeds?

Comment: @Micro - as I said it is the first couple of characters. The length does not matter very much. This is related to the math of hashing. In your example `photos` will cause collisions. Remember there are no directories in Cloud Storage. The directory part is actually just part of the filename. All files exist in the root directory so to speak.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's rather odd of them to represent the directory structure in the Google Cloud Console if it's actually flat.

Comment: Anyhow, our app does something more like the following: photos-bucket/[user_id]/img-[random_string].jpg

Comment: @JohnHanley right, so maybe what my SO question should be is where does the file name actually start. You are saying it starts with `photos` in my example.

Comment: Your object name is the entire string of characters. There is no directory, there is no path separator. Just a string of characters.

Comment: @JohnHanley take a look doug's answer for me please?

Comment: @Micro - I comment on Doug's answer.